# Java design pattern to allow sdk to support multiple authentication schemes

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am designing an sdk/client library for a http api. The api support multiple authentication mechanisms: basic auth, oauth, digest etc.

My client library is simple at the moment like this:

```
public MyAPIRestClient implements MyAPIClient {

   public MyAPIRestClient(String endpoint, String user, String pass){
    login(user, pass)
   }

   public void login(String user, String pass){
    //http code to login and get a cookie etc.
   }

   public Book getBook(String name){
    // http code to get a book
   }

}
```

What is the best design pattern to enable me to have multiple authentication mechanisms, without having to code all possible auth methods in the same client class? And to enable future auth mechanisms to easily be injected?

Comment: Sounds like a factory pattern may be helpful here. I would consider removing the word "best" from your question, as you may face closure on the grounds of "opinion-based".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that came to my mind is the strategy pattern:

```
public abstract class Authenticator{ //or interface
    public abstract boolean login(String user, String password);
}
```

The `Authenticator` is the pattern. You can extend/implement it with various authentication methods. In your main class you hold a specific pattern in a member, which you then call directly:

```
public class Main{
    private Authenticator auth;

    //choose auth in constructor or by choosing it in a List in some GUI
    //and create an Object that extends/implements Authenticator

    public void login(String user, String password){
        if(auth.login(user, password)){
            //do whatever is needed to complete login
        }
    }

}
```

This way you have minute control over which authentification method(s) are used.

If you change `auth` to an array or ArrayList, it is essentially the same as @Konrad Garus answer.

Comment: Thanks, the different auth mechanisms will need different parameters though. So for my BasicAuthenticator I would need login(String user, String pass) and for APIKeyAuthenticator for example I would need login(String apiKey). Can this work with this pattern?

Comment: @jonlee You could pass the `apiKey` as parameter to the constructor or maybe generate it from the username (I don't know how APIKey authenticication works). Based on the username you could read it from a file or something.

Answer (score 2):

It is an odd thing to do you by yourself when this matter is very complex, difficult and has very good mature solutions including Apache Shiro and Spring Security. But I assume it's just an exercise in design patterns.

I would probably go for the chain of responsibility pattern. Have a generic interface like:

```
interface Authenticator {
    /**
    * Analyze the request and return an Authentication object
    * upon success, or null otherwise
    */
    Authentication authenticate(HttpServletRequest request);
}
```

Implement it for each authentication mechanism, checking cookies, POST data or what have you.

Then, call them like:

```
public Authentication authenticateRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    for (Authenticator ator : supportedAuthenticators) {
        Authentication a = ator.authenticate(request);
        if (a != null) {
            // Logged in successfully!
            return a;
        }
    }
    throw new LoginFailed();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Forgive if I'm wrong, but I think your example is more for the server side where you can analyse the request to see what type of auth to use. I want it for the client side where users of the client can just say new RestClient().authentication(BASIC).build() type of thing.

Comment: So for my BasicAuthenticator I would need authenticate(String user, String pass) and for APIKeyAuthenticator for example I would need authenticate(String apiKey) can this type of thing work with this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have an interface which will have signatures of basic authentication methods,and the implementing class can have different definitions of those authentication methods.